# Before and After hooks for a spec directory in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

We have quite a bit of tests in our RSpec test suite. directory structure looks something like -

```
spec/
  truncation/
    example1_spec.rb
    example2_spec.rb
    ...
  transaction/
    example1_spec.rb
    example2_spec.rb
    ...
```

I wanted to restore a test database dump, before all of the spec files in `transaction/` folder are run and empty it after all tests finish.

Is there a way to do this?

There are `before(:suite)` and `after(:suite)` hooks but these work for individual spec files.

Is there a way to provide before and after hooks for directories in RSpec?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using RSpec 3+?

You can use `#define_derived_metadata` to add custom metadata based on file path matchers.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.define_derived_metadata(file_path: %r{spec/truncation}) do |metadata|
    metadata[:truncation] = true
  end

  config.before(:all, :truncation) do
    # truncate that bad boy
  end
end
```

This is the [same method](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/a09a6231ceecefa177ec08b27c3066d5947e5899/lib/rspec/rails/configuration.rb#L85) used in `rspec-rails` to add custom behavior to specs in the specific directories, e.g. `spec/controllers`.

[Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration:define_derived_metadata)